# NHibernate mapping ParentId in child table without collection

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, one-to-many

i'm pretty new to nHibernate and am trying to create what I thought should be a relatively simple mapping, using XML not fluent nHibernate, as follows:

In my database:

User Table

```
  [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1)
, [Username] varchar(250) NOT NULL
```

.. etc

Organisation Table

```
  [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1)
, [Name] varchar(500) NOT NULL
, [MainContactId] int NOT NULL
, [Sector] nvarchar(1000) NULL
```

MainContactId references a user in the User table.

In my object model I have a User class and an Organisation class, and all i want is to have a property on the Organisation class as follows:

```
public class Organisation
{
  ...
  public User MainContact { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

I do NOT want to have a collection on the User class that references the Organisation, as every article I have read seems so far has - surely this must be possible and straightforward?

Thanks in advance,

Jamie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`many-to-one`](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone) mapping for that.

```
<class name="Organisation" table="Organisation">
    <!-- ... -->
    <many-to-one name="MainContact" column="MainContactId" />
    <!-- ... -->
</class>
```

[Ayende](http://ayende.com/blog/) has a good post about `many-to-one` mapping: [NHibernate Mapping - `<many-to-one />`](http://ayende.com/blog/3938/nhibernate-mapping-many-to-one).

Comment: Thanks! I feel like an idiot after all of the combinations I've tried! Much appreciated though :)